# cpan App::cpanminus fails with multiple errors: "Giving up parsing your /Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz, too many errors"

Tags: perl, installation, module, cpan, cpanm

I am trying to install App::cpanminus Perl module using `cpan App::cpanminus`. I am getting the following errors. How can I fix the errors and install the module?

```
% cpan App::cpanminus
Reading '/Users/foo/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz'
............................................................................DONE
Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
http://mirrors.ccs.neu.edu/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
HTTP::Tiny failed with an internal error: Could not connect to 'mirrors.ccs.neu.edu:80': nodename nor servname provided, or not known


Trying with
    /usr/local/bin/wget -O "/Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz.tmp73271"
to get
    http://mirrors.ccs.neu.edu/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
--2021-11-02 11:31:07--  http://mirrors.ccs.neu.edu/CPAN/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Resolving mirrors.ccs.neu.edu (mirrors.ccs.neu.edu)... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'mirrors.ccs.neu.edu'

...
Saving to: '/Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz.tmp73271'

/Users/foo/.cpan/source     [ <=>                                              ]  43.63K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s  

2021-11-02 11:31:08 (34.3 MB/s) - '/Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz.tmp73271' saved [44681]

Reading '/Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz'
Warning: Your /Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Line-Count header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Warning: Your /Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz does not contain a Last-Updated header.
Please check the validity of the index file by comparing it to more
than one CPAN mirror. I'll continue but problems seem likely to
happen.
Could not split line[""]
Could not split line[""]
.Could not split line["    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)"]
Could not split line["    {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?"]
Giving up parsing your /Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz, too many errors
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like there were attempt to download the file using multiple methods, and all of them failed, leaving you with no file or an empty file.

This points to a networking issue. You'll need to fix your network issues to continue. Perhaps you need to use a different mirror, or perhaps the downloaders need to be directed to use a proxy.

Note that you can delete the file, forcing another attempt to download it.

---

Update: I checked the validity of the URL your `cpan` is configured to use (`http://mirrors.ccs.neu.edu/CPAN`), and it's bad. The name `mirrors.ccs.neu.edu` can't be resolved. As such, you need to configure `cpan` to use a different mirror.

To tell `cpan` to use something else, run `cpan`. From within, use either `o conf init urllist` or `o conf urllist http://www.cpan.org/`. Don't forget to save the setting using `o conf commit` before exiting (`quit`).

You could also use something like

```sh
printf '%s\n%s\n' 'o conf urllist http://www.cpan.org/' 'o conf commit' | cpan
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Note that I solved the issue - simply posted the Q&A. I did not mention that I first tried deleting this file using `rm /Users/foo/.cpan/sources/modules/*`, but that did not fix the issue (surprisingly). Only moving the entire `.cpan` worked. I wonder why, though...

Comment: Re "*I first tried deleting this file*", Deleting the file won't help an inability to download it. It just forces another attempt to download it.

Comment: Re "*simply posted the Q&A*", yeah, but the answer was wrong. The problem wasn't a corrupted file.

Comment: Deleting the file should have forced to re-download a fresh copy of the file. Not sure why it did not work though. But `mv .cpan .cpan.bak` worked. Why then?

Comment: Re "*Deleting the file should have forced to re-download a fresh copy of the file*", Yes, and the download would have failed again because, like I said twice already, the problem wasn't a corrupted file. /// Re "*Not sure why it did not work*", Deleting the file doesn't solve the fact that you were using an invalid URL. /// Re "*But mv .cpan .cpan.bak worked. Why then?*", Because that resulted in doing `o conf init urllist` (among other things). You went from using `http://mirrors.ccs.neu.edu/CPAN/` to using something else such as `http://www.cpan.org/`.

Comment: Bear with me please, I have not been using `cpan` for a while... Just to make sure... `mv .cpan .cpan.bak` worked because this caused to download a fresh list of CPAN mirrors, which contained working URLS, and no non-working URLs. But using your solution is perhaps a more direct way of fixing the incorrect URL. Is this correct?

Comment: Deleting `cpan`'s config file (`~/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`) caused a new one to be generated. The old config had `http://mirrors.ccs.neu.edu/CPAN/` for the `urllist` item. (The problem.) The new config has something different. (The fix.)

Comment: Got it now. I really appreciate your patient explanations!

Comment: No problem. Sorry I wasn't clearer. Made some tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Even though the answer below worked for me, I later learned of a better answer, plus the correct explanation of the root cause. Please see the answer above from *ikegami* for the preferred and accepted method. Keeping the answer below for historical purposes, and because it also works.**

<strike>The cause of the error is that file `02packages.details.txt.gz`, and/or possibly other files are corrupted.</strike> Move `.cpan` directory to a new location and rerun the command again. It should now work.

```
cd && mv .cpan .cpan-bak
cpan App::cpanminus
```

Prints:

```
CPAN.pm requires configuration, but most of it can be done automatically.
If you answer 'no' below, you will enter an interactive dialog for each
configuration option instead.

Would you like to configure as much as possible automatically? [yes] 
...
  MIYAGAWA/App-cpanminus-1.7044.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make install  -- OK
```

This confirmed working solution was copied from [this answer by *Arjuna Del Toso* to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6876547/967621), to whom all the credit should go. I am posting it here so that a search for this error message leads to this page with a working solution.